# Is there any general chatbot with public API?

Tags: chatbot

I'm looking for a chatbot for testing purpose. I found most chatbot related pages are chatbot builder, but what I want is a existing chatbot service with API which I can used for my project testing. Google Assistance and Alexa could be ideal, but is there anything for general chat? Child chat robot would be ideal.

Comment: Try Dialogue flow: https://dialogflow.com/

Comment: @new_user It is just a tool for robot building, not the product ready or beta version of a general chatbot :( So far, I found mitsuku is pretty nice, but it doesn't have free plan :( I'm working on a demo project.

Comment: There are pre existing samples that you can add easily and test in dialogflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the general chatbots are perfect, but here are something you can use (or based on them).

- Julie on botlibre.com
- Another you can try, https://www.personalityforge.com/
- mitsuku could be found from https://www.pandorabots.com/

Comment: Julie on https://www.botlibre.com can be accessed through the Bot Libre API, as well as thousands of other bots, https://www.botlibre.com/api.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there isn't for obvious reasons.

Comment: I found few, will share on the answser

Comment: Ah yeah, that level can be found for sure. I was thinking more at the level of XiaoIce etc.

Comment: Ah yeah, that level can be found for sure. I was thinking more at the level of XiaoIce etc.